# Long text in tooltip is not fully shown in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, tooltip

I've defined a  for a listbox item, and binded the text inside the tooltip to two properties of the object (name + description) but i have an issue that the text is being cut off

here is my tooltip:

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock FontSize="13">
                <Bold>Name</Bold>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock FontSize="13" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <Bold>Description</Bold>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind description}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

Now the thing is, if i bind the tooltip to a method that returns the name + description (Which is how it was previously, but was super ugly) it does show all the text, it was like this:

```
 <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Description}"/>
 </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

But I needed to style it to make it look better, so i've tried to do what was posted above.
I've already tried setting the Width/Height to super large values, didn't do anything. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip template probably has a default maximum width, which cuts off the `TextBlock`. To solve this, just add `TextWrapping` attribute:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind description}"/>
```

Now the tooltip text will wrap on multiple lines as necessary